# Allocating GPU memory for cupy arrays

Tags: cupy

I have a tensorflow session running in parallel to this cupy code. I have allocated 8 Gb out of 16 Gb of my total gpu memory to the tensorflow session. What I want now is to allocate 2 Gb from the rest of 7 Gb for executing this cupy code. The actual code is more involved than the example code I provided. In my actual code, cp_arr is a result of a series of array operations. But I want cp_array to be allocated in the specified 2 Gb space of my gpu memory. Remember, freeing the gpu resources by closing out tensorflow session is not an option.

This is the code I am using.

```
memory = cp.cuda.Memory(2048000000)
ptr = cp.cuda.MemoryPointer(memory,0)
cp_arr = cp.ndarray(shape=(30,1080,1920,3),memptr=ptr)
cp_arr = ** Array operations **
```

In this case, an additional memory of 1.7 GB was allocated when 'cp_arr = ** Array operations **' is being executed. What I want is to make use of the allocated space of 2 GB to hold my cupy array, cp_arr. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation behavior of CuPy is similar to that of NumPy.

Like as in NumPy, several functions support `out` argument which can be used to store the computation results into specified array. e.g., https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.dot.html

Comment: Hi Kenichi, thanks for your reply. Let me reframe the scenario. My tensorflow session is eating up 8 gb out of 16 gb of memory. Now I want to allocate 3 gb of the remaining 8gb for executing a particular cupy piece of code. What is the way to do it?

Comment: CuPy dev team is planning to support "upper limit" feature to the memory pool in near future. (https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/1295)
When the limit is enabled, CuPy will raise an error if requested amount of memory allocation exceeds the configured limit. Does this feature meets your needs?

Comment: Yes, that meets my need. But, right now, is there no way to accomplish this? In that case, can you tell me how do you free memory allocated to some cupy arrays?

Comment: Thanks. Please refer to the example code here. https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/upgrade.html#default-memory-pool

Comment: Thanks Kenichi, the last link was very helpful. It does my job for now.